# drawing rounded rectangle in cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I cant seem to find the right code to be able to draw a rectangle (rounded corners) inside each custom cell of a uitableview. How should I do this and where does the code go? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the UIBezierPath documentation. You can use the method `+ bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cornerRadius:` of `UIBezierPath`. Place it in the drawing method of your cell.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use a background image for the cell which has a rounded rectangle drawn in it?

Comment: No I cant because the rectangle changes on user input

Comment: I would go with Hetal's suggestion, you can swap the image for something else when it is selected.  Using images is cleaner solution in my opinion.

Comment: I have done both methods. Using a high quality background image appropriately sized for use with the `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` method of UIImage is far superior. When you say the "rectangle changes" what do you mean? If the size changes, the stretchable image will still work fine. If the color changes, you would need a different background image for each color you support. Not a big deal really.